# Unsure what function app trigger to use for matching two blobs with same name but different file types

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have encrypted data being pushed into a blob storage container in Azure. The data comes with the encrypted bin file, and a flg file to flag that its ready to decrypt. The data intake of the blob container is large number of files daily. I then use a function app to detect the blobs and decrypt them.

My current solution I'm exploring is using a blob trigger in the function app to detect when a flg file gets uploaded and check the blob storage if the corresponding bin file exists. This is where I realized that if it doesn't exist, which is high probability if the bin file wasn't uploaded before the flg file, then that pair will be ignored and never decrypted. So, this solution was a no go.

To improve on it I then thought what if I have two triggers checking for bin and flg files simultaneously. But again, if the files don't upload in the right order, some files might get missed out. Again, solution is a no go.

My last-ditch effort is to use a daily timer trigger that takes in all the files, goes through the flg files one by one checking if the corresponding bin file exists and decrypts it moving on to the next file. However ideally, we want to use an event-based solution for efficiency. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas I can look into as to what type of trigger best fits this problem and what solution might work if blob trigger is appropriate?

Comment: file Name is fixed, or file name will vary every time @Alex Botez

Comment: The file names vary slightly. They all share the same name but have attacked to the name a date and time which references the order they need to be decrypted. E.g. decryptfile_{date}_{time}.flg/bin

But the .flg and .bin files are matched so that for every bin file there is a flag file with the same name, date, time format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas, in the order in which I would prefer them:

1. The source system puts a message into a Service Bus or storage queue indicating that both files have been uploaded. You trigger on that message and process both files.
2. Your process follows an exponential backoff retry pattern, basically accepting that you will fail some number of times before you succeed. I would consider this less desirable because of the work you must do to handle this failure well, especially if you have alerts configured on errors in logs of the function. Reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=exponential-backoff%2Cisolated-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#retry-strategies

Comment: These are good suggestions thanks! I agree the first one sounds better as its more straightforward. I'm sure if I tried the retry method I'd mess something up.

Going to give that a go with the Service Bus trigger thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome, please accept the answer? The fake internet points are important!

Comment: Sorry, first post on Stack. Didn't realize I had to accept an answer.